# Python - Lambda function on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have a pandas dataframe that I would prefer to use a lambda function rather than a loop to solve my problem.

The problem is as such;

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'my_fruits':['fruit', 'fruit', 'fruit', 'fruit', 'fruit'],
         'fruit_a': ['apple', 'banana', 'vegetable', 'vegetable', 'cherry'],
         'fruit_b': ['vegetable', 'apple', 'vegeatble', 'pineapple', 'pear']})
```

If I apply the following loop;

```
for i in np.arange(0,len(df)):
    if df['fruit_a'][i] == 'vegetable' or df['fruit_b'][i] == 'vegetable':
        df['my_fruits'][i] = 'not_fruit'
```

I am able to get the result that I want. This is that if either of the `fruit_a` or `fruit_b` columns containing the value `vegetable`, I want the `my_fruits` column to be equal to `not_fruit`.

How can I possible set this up in a lamda function. Was not able to understand how two columns inputs can be used to change a different columns values. Thanks!

Comment: I don't get the question.  A lambda *expression* is simply an alternative syntax for defining a function in the special case of when the function body consists of only `return <expression>`.  A function is not an alternative for a `for` loop.  The alternative to certain special cases of for loop is a comprehension, but your loop is not such a special case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) by `boolean mask`:

```
mask = (df['fruit_a'] == 'vegetable') | (df['fruit_b'] == 'vegetable')
print (mask)
0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
4    False
dtype: bool


df.my_fruits = df.my_fruits.mask(mask, 'not_fruits')
print (df)
     fruit_a    fruit_b   my_fruits
0      apple  vegetable  not_fruits
1     banana      apple       fruit
2  vegetable  vegetable  not_fruits
3  vegetable  pineapple  not_fruits
4     cherry       pear       fruit
```

Another solution for `mask` is compare all selected columns by `vegetable` and then get all `True` at least in one column by [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
print ((df[['fruit_a', 'fruit_b']] == 'vegetable'))
  fruit_a fruit_b
0   False    True
1   False   False
2    True    True
3    True   False
4   False   False

mask = (df[['fruit_a', 'fruit_b']] == 'vegetable').any(axis=1) 
print (mask)
0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
4    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Much appreciated for the alternative method

Comment: Thank you for accepting, yes, another method is better if many columns.

Answer (score 3):

you can do this with [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method:

```
>>> df.my_fruits = df.apply(lambda x: 'not_fruit' if x['fruit_a'] == 'vegetable' or x['fruit_b'] == 'vegetable' else x['my_fruits'], axis=1)
0    not_fruit
1        fruit
2    not_fruit
3    not_fruit
4        fruit
```

Or you can do it like this:

```
>>> df.my_fruits[(df['fruit_a'] == 'vegetable') | (df['fruit_b'] == 'vegetable')] = 'not_fruit'
>>> df
     fruit_a    fruit_b  my_fruits
0      apple  vegetable  not_fruit
1     banana      apple      fruit
2  vegetable  vegeatble  not_fruit
3  vegetable  pineapple  not_fruit
4     cherry       pear      fruit
```

Comment: agreed, just wanted to show how it could be done with lambda function

Comment: Sure, alternative solution is better.

Comment: Thanks, this at least shows me how it could be done with apply. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Using `pd.Series.where` and checking if `'vegetable'` in one step combined with `any`.
`where` is opposite of `mask` which is why I use the negation of `cond`.
Otherwise, this is very similar in spirit to jezrael's answer

```
cond = df[['fruit_a', 'fruit_b']].eq('vegetable').any(1)
df.my_fruits = df.my_fruits.where(~cond, 'not_fruit')
```

Answered from my phone.  Please forgive typos.